# Backspace not working in form with complex associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Final Update:**

I found out what the problem was.  I am running linux and on it you can't use backspace to go back which I love to do.  So I had an extension running which was causing this error.  I'm unsure if it was an update that broke it, as I don't remember ever having the issue.

**UPDATE 2:**

So I found out this doesn't work anywhere there is a number input form anywhere on my app.  It only does this on Chrome.

**Original:**

So I have a form that accepts attributes for a complex "rich" join. Or a "has_many through:" join.  When I enter into an input field, say "97.8" and go to change the 8 to a 7 by hitting the backspace it instead uses the browser's back page.  Any other normal form I create works fine.

The below is my form

```
= simple_form_for @student do |f|
  = f.fields_for :student_classes do |ff|
    = f.input :grade
    = f.association :class
```

Then in my controller I have

```
def new
    @student = Student.new
    @student.student_classes.build.build_class
end
```

In my Student model I have:

```
has_many :student_classes
has_many :classes, through: :student_classes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :student_classes
```

In my StudentClass model I have

```
belongs_to :student
belongs_to :class
accepts_nested_attributes_for :class
```

And finally in my Class model I have

```
has_many :student_classes
has_many :students, through: :student_classes
```

Any help you can give would be wonderful.  It's a very weird problem that I am having.

**Update:**

I figured out it is just the inputs accepting floats that don't backspace.  If it accepts a string then it works fine.

Comment: Is this a browser specific behavior?

Comment: Yes, I just checked it on firefox and it works.  So it only does this on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event handler to the backspace keydown (code is `8`) with javascript and then do whatever you want when it's pressed. In your case, you would want to additionally filter whether the keydown happened inside of your input fields:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
  if (e.which === 8 && $(e.target).is("input, textarea")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    <do whatever you want>
  }
});
```

or if you prefer coffeescript:

```
$(document).on "keydown", (e) ->
  if e.which is 8 and $(e.target).is("input, textarea")
    e.preventDefault()
    <do whatever you want>
    return
```

You can change the selector `input, textarea` to match the type, class, or id of the input(s) you need.

Ah, the warm and fuzzy world of cross-browser interoperability...

Comment: I figured out that it doesn't have to do with different browsers.  It's simply I was running Chrome on linux with the extension to allow the backspace to be used to go back.  I don't know if there was an update that caused it to break or what.